# FileIO.AppendTextAsync throwing random exceptions when used in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, async-await

So I have a bit of a peculiar problem. I have a set of methods like so:

```
StorageFile file;
public void WriteStuff() //This implements an interface, so can't be changed to async with a task returned
{
    Write();
}
async void Write()
{
  await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, DateTime.Now + " testing!"+Environment.NewLine);
}
async void Create()
{
  file=await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.txt", CreationCollisionOptions.OpenIfExists);
}
```

and then code actually using it like so:

```
var x=new Foo();
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
  x.WriteStuff(); //can't use async/await from here. This is in a portable class library
}
```

Whenever I call `Test`, I get very random errors. Things like FileNotFound, AccessDenied, AccessViolation, etc.

It appears to only happen when calling `AppendTextAsync` many times asynchronously. I would've imagined an asynchronous API would be.. well, thread safe, but apparently not. Is this true?

Also, how would I fix this without modifying my calling code?

Comment: Sorry, but you _need_ to use `async Task`.

Comment: Asynchrony has nothing to do with threading.  Async APIs are rarely thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to do this, then your only choice is to synchronously `Wait()` for the asynchronous method to complete (or use `Result`):

```
void Write()
{
    FileIO.AppendTextAsync(
        file, DateTime.Now + " testing!"+Environment.NewLine).Wait();
}

void Create()
{
    file = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
        "test.txt", CreationCollisionOptions.OpenIfExists).Result;
}
```

But this defeats the whole purpose of asynchronous code, so you really should avoid doing this. Also, if the code you're calling isn't written properly, doing this will cause a deadlock.

> can't use async/await from here. This is in a portable class library

You *can* use `async`-`await` from a PCL. You just need to target platforms that support it and possibly also reference Microsoft.Bcl.Async, if you have platforms that don't support it natively.

Comment: @SLaks Like I said, it may deadlock, depending on how are the called async methods implemented. (It won't deadlock if they use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere or if they aren't implemented using `async`-`await` and so don't capture the current context.)